# How to call method after click using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a button click event where I added javascript confirmation box (Yes / No). I want to make when the user click yes the method will run. Here is the sample:

Asp.Net C# Backend:

```
Response.Write("<script>var confirmdelete=confirm('No chronological event found.Do you want to continue ?');if (confirmdelete) {('<%=ASPxButton_Approve%>').valueof()}</script>");
```

ASPxButton_Approve = is the button I will trigger

after that it will show yes no confirmation box. I want to make it when the user will click yes below method will run:

```
approve();
```

Answer (score 1):

on button clientclick only you can write

eg.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" TabIndex="5" ValidationGroup="validate" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="if (Page_ClientValidate()){ return confirm('Do you want to add task? Click OK to proceed.')}" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use OnClientClick attribute, in your frontend file put a button like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="optionalParameterLikeAKey" 
OnCommand="lnkDelete_Command" OnClientClick="return confirm('No 
chronological event found.Do you want to continue ?');" Text="Delete">
```

And in code behind catch the action command "Delete":

```
void lnkDelete_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    //Code to delete -> e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
<a href="YourPage.aspx?ID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>&action=delete" onclick="return confirm('No 
chronological event found.Do you want to continue ?');">Delete</a>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to make a `javascript` function and use `CustomValidator`in ASP.NET which is a strong ability to handle client side codes.

> To create custom validation logic on the client
>   Create a validation function in ECMAScript (JavaScript, JScript):
>   The following code example illustrates custom client-side validation. An excerpt from the page shows a TextBox control referenced by a CustomValidator control. The validation control calls a client script function named validateLength to make sure that the user has entered at least eight characters into the TextBox control.

A Typical example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function validateLength(oSrc, args){
   args.IsValid = (args.Value.length >= 8);
}
</script>
```

The C# code:

```
<asp:Textbox id="text1" runat="server" text=""></asp:Textbox>
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate = "text1"
ErrorMessage = "You must enter at least 8 characters!"
ClientValidationFunction="validateLength" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

For more information go on [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx).